# php array to radio button

Tags: php, arrays, radio-button, dynamic-arrays

i want to create a radio button labeled with the values of my array. all i can do is to print them all. what can i use to access my array (dynamic-array) besides indexes since i will not know the order and number of files inside my languages directory? Thanks!

input

```
english.xml,mandarin.xml,french.xml
```

these files is saved at languages and i will use the file names as labels in my radio button form.

```
$files = glob("languages/*.xml");

foreach($files as $file){

   $file = substr($file, 10); //removes "languages/"
   $file = substr_replace($file, "", -4); //removes ".xml"
   ?>

   <p><?=$file?></p> // prints out the filename
   <?}?>
```

output

```
<form action="">
<input type="radio" name="lang" value="english">english
<input type="radio" name="lang" value="mandarin">mandarin
<input type="radio" name="lang" value="french">french
</form>
```

sorry for my bad english i hope i explained it well.

Comment: Its really hard to understand, what you want? Could be please show the input array and output you want?

Comment: Ok, so what does echo $file give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `[]` you can add elements to an array. The order will be the order you've placed them in, which is the same as the `$files` array you're looping through.

The [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function can get the name of a file (without directory or extension).

```
function getLangs() {
    $langs = array();
    $files = glob("languages/*.xml");

    foreach($files as $file) {
        $lang = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $langs[] = $lang;
    }

    return $langs;
}
```

Now print it using

```
$langs = getLangs();

foreach ($langs as $lang) {
   echo "<label><input type='radio' name='lang' value='$lang' /> $lang</label>";
}
```

Instead of using `echo` you could build up a template like

```
<form action=''>
<?php foreach ($langs as $lang): ?>
   <label><input type="radio" name="lang" value="<?= $lang ?> /> value="<?= $lang ?></label>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Note that it isn't required to use a function, but it's good practice to separate the *do* from the *view*.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the key of the array using foreach too. Like this:

```
foreach($files as $key => $value) {
    //....
}
```